# sucesión convergente (Convergent sequence)

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a convergent sequence on $R^n$, and $x_k\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}x$. Let $s_k:=\|x_k\|$. Prove what the the sequence $\{s_k: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, and $s_k\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}\|x\|$. Just looking for a hint.

Comment: Show that the map $x \mapsto \|x\|$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @JoséLópez: Welcome to MSE. It is a policy to ask for OPs's (the person who asks a question) to provide some context to their question: whether this is a problem form a book you are studying, if you have tried something and gets stuck (in which case, maybe you show the idea you tried and where you are stuck), etc. Questions that do not include such type of context tent to be down voted and closed. Try to add some context. If you have problems writing this in English, there is always that will help with that be editing or translating your question.

Comment: Hint: The triangle inequality in the form $\big|\|x\|-\|y\|\big|\leq \|x-y\|$ may be of help here.